# How to Print or Export to PDF without truncation in Mathematica 12.1

Tags: pdf-format, printing

My notebook looks fine on screen, but Dataset output is truncated in printing. I've read similar queries (as long back as 6 years ago) and experimented thoroughly with no success (including all print options). Cannot submit my work report without a PDF. Is that impossible in Mathematica for some reason? If not, can someone post a reference to a tutorial. Is Wolfram Player the only workaround (likely not feasible in my work situation)?

Comment: If you go to Preferences > Advanced, have a look at _"Maximum output size before truncation"_. Mine is set to 1048576 bytes (or 1MiB) - maybe increasing it by a bit will help?

Comment: By truncation I mean at the margins of the printed page, not in size of the file. Same happens to graphics that look fine on screen but don't adjust properly for printing.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code that produces stuff which goes off the page as you're experiencing?